# Inconsistent parameter value on returning observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-services

I'm having a hard time using Angular RxJS observables.

```
getOptions(): Observable<PickQuality[]> {
    // Fetches content from my service
}

choose(n?: number): Observable<PickQuality[]> {
    var chosenObserver: Observer<PickQuality[]>;
    alert(n); // <---- 1st alert

    return this.getOptions().map(options => {
            alert(n); // <---- 2nd alert

            var sorted = options.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
            var chosen: PickQuality[];

            if(n) chosen = sorted.slice(0, n);
            else chosen = sorted.slice(0, 1);

            return chosen;
    });

}
```

I'm making the following calls to my `choose()` function:

```
    test.choose().subscribe(a => console.log(a));
    test.choose(5).subscribe(b => console.log(b));
    test.choose(15).subscribe(c => console.log(c));
```

The 3 1st alerts print properly (undefined, 5, 15). But the 3 2nd alerts print "15" 3 times and I don't know why. The final result is also incorrect, as my funtion will always return a 15-sized slice.

Comment: I removed the type annotations and ran this through jsbin quickly, and it produced the results you want. I think the issue lies in code you haven't included in your sample. Can you reproduce your issue with this code outside your TypeScript class?

Comment: What type annotations do you mean? I can't reproduce it cause it uses a bunch of codes from a couple of other classes and it runs on a Angular server, which I don't know how to do online.

Comment: I meant I reduced your TypeScript to ES6 and it ran fine. Take a look here: https://jsbin.com/wirinikuli/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @MattBurnell FYI, JSBin supports TypeScript, so there is no need to go through that trouble.

Comment: So it does; thank you for telling me. Unfortunately the TS version (https://jsbin.com/royiruyaho/edit?js,console,output) does not exhibit the described behavior, either.